# Looking for a home

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to find a suitable forum in which to ask [my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/235642). It's been rejected as off-topic in two places so far, and I wonder if this might be a good place for it.

Would this question be welcome here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Coding questions are off-topic here.

Not all questions have a home somewhere on Stack Exchange.  Some are simply not suitable for the Stack Exchange format, or don't fall within the scope of any existing Stack Exchange site.

Also, it's currently posted on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/59756073/781723) and has an answer there.  We don't allow cross-posting the same question on multiple sites; that has the potential to waste answerer's time.

Comment: Actually, the [answer to my question](if you will only usually want a piece of the list) turns out to indicate that it *would* have been a good fit here. What I was looking for was the Computer Science behind the logic. What do you think?

Comment: @InteXX, I haven't seen the answer, but I don't see how it would change anything.  We judge whether questions are in-scope based on the contents of the question, not the contents of the answer.  (How could we do anything else?  We typically have to judge the question before we see answers.)  In any case, the question asks the reader to explain a piece of code.  That is off-topic, regardless of what the answer turns out to be.

Comment: It's possible I phrased the question incorrectly for this site.